# The resource cannot be found + Sharepoint 2010 Mapped Folder + Feature

Tags: 2010

I use Mapped Sharepoint Folder, to add a Sharepoint file (versions.aspx) into my solution ( to do a customization ).

If I deactivate the feature, file "versions.aspx" is deleted from Sharepoint (The resource cannot be found. 
) ... how can i prevent this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior for feature deactivation. When you deactivate, SharePoint is cleaning up after itself. If you need to deactivate, and you want the file to remain, then you may want to consider other ways to provision that page.